# Track starting new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-logcat

I want to track new activity start , I use this code to only get I:ActivityManager :

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                            "/system/bin/logcat ActivityManager:I");
```

but it gets all logcat and do not filter with such tag .

where is the problem ?

visit this link :

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput

Comment: do you just want to log the start of an Activity? Because you can just add Log.d("TAG", "activity started"); within your overridden onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `logcat` to hide the other messages.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        "/system/bin/logcat *:S ActivityManager:I");
```

`*:S` turns everything else silent